# Visual Studio - Start / Stop Windows Service Name that has spaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, service

I am modifying the code below to start/stop FileZilla Server. The issue I am having is with the service name having spaces in it. When I use sc start FileZilla Server in the command prompt, it requires double quotes around it (sc start "FileZilla Server"). Of course when I pass the code:

```
Dim sc As New ServiceController("FileZilla Server")
```

It doesn't leave the quotes, so I get the erorr that the service doesn't exist on the system. If I escape the quotes like:

```
Dim sc As New ServiceController("""FileZilla Server""")
```

I get the same error even though through debugging I can see the that the service name is being passed with quotes. I have confirmed that typing it in quotes in the command prompt is working and that passing a service name that consists of one word works. Any idea how to get this to work?

```
' If it is started (running, paused, etc), stop the service.
' If it is stopped, start the service.
Dim sc As New ServiceController("""FileZilla Server""")
Console.WriteLine("The FileZilla service status is currently set to {0}", sc.Status)

If sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
   ' Start the service if the current status is stopped.
   Console.WriteLine("Starting the FileZilla service...")
   sc.Start()
Else
   ' Stop the service if its status is not set to "Stopped".
   Console.WriteLine("Stopping the FileZilla service...")
   sc.Stop()
End If

' Refresh and display the current service status.
sc.Refresh()
Console.WriteLine("The FileZilla service status is now set to {0}.", sc.Status)
```

Comment: Are you sure FileZilla Server is the service name? In my experience service names don't contain spaces. Maybe you are using the displayname. Go to services and check the service name.

Comment: Yeah I've checked it in services and on the services tab in Task Manager. You're right though, while scrolling down the services in Task Manager, only 3 or 4 are more than one word. Most of them are Intel services but also FileZilla, SolarWinds and my FitBit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display name and the actual name of the Service can be different. For example:

[image]

So you can just find the service name from the Services and use that...

But you can find the service from the display name like this:

```
'this requires a reference to system.ServiceProcess adding
Dim sc = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.DisplayName = "FileZilla Server FTP server")
If sc Is Nothing Then Return
```

Either of these work for me:

```
    Dim sc = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ServiceName = "FileZilla Server")

    Dim sc = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.DisplayName = "FileZilla Server FTP server")
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt Wilko. I tried using that code. I had to change the display name to "FileZilla Server FTP Server" since that is what the properties show the display name as but sc still returns Nothing. Tried it with just "Filezilla Server" and it returned Nothing as well. If I use a service such as "Fax" it works fine.

Comment: Looked in the registry just to verify the service name and it appears as "Filezilla Server".

Comment: See my edit. Note on the Display name server is all lower case

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It's working like it should now